# E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, installation

I am trying to download mongodb and I am following the steps on this [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#install-the-mongodb-packages).

But when I get to the step:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org  //This is the error
```

Why is this occurring and is there a work around?

Answer (score 235, accepted):

I have faced the same issue but then fixed it by the changing the package file section command. The steps that I followed were:

First try with this command:

```bash
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb
```

This is the unofficial mongodb package provided by Ubuntu and it is not maintained by MongoDB and conflicts with MongoDB’s officially supported packages.

If the above command doesn't work then you can fix the issue by one of the following procedures:

#### Step 1:  Import the MongoDB public key

In Ubuntu 18.*+, you may get invalid signatures. --recv value may need to be updated to `EA312927`.

See here for more details on the invalid signature issue: [MongoDB GPG - Invalid Signatures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733340/mongodb-gpg-invalid-signatures)

```bash
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
```

#### Step 2: Generate a file with the MongoDB repository url

```bash
echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
```

#### Step 3: Refresh the local database with the packages

```bash
sudo apt-get update
```

#### Step 4: Install the last stable MongoDB version and all the necessary packages on our system

```bash
sudo apt-get install mongodb-org
```

Or if the unofficial mongodb package provided by Ubuntu is not maintained by MongoDB and conflict with MongoDB’s officially supported packages. Use the official MongoDB mongodb-org packages, which are kept up-to-date with the most recent major and minor MongoDB releases.

```bash
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb
```

Hope this will work for you also. You can follow this [MongoDB](http://www.mongodbspain.com/en/2014/08/30/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-14-04/)

### Update

The above instruction will install mongodb 2.6 version, if you want to install latest version for `Ubuntu 12.04` then just omit the above `step 2` and follow below instruction instead of that:

#### Step 2: Generate a file with the MongoDB repository url

```
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
```

If you are using `Ubuntu 14.04` then use bellow step instead of above `step 2`

#### Step 2: Generate a file with the MongoDB repository url

```
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
```

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 14.10 (other answers did not) after I fixed the command in step 2.

Comment: Ooops, no, sorry, still not working (this installs Mongo `2.6`, not the lastest stable `3.0`). See my own answer.

Comment: It sucks that this works and the official site guide does not.

Comment: MongoDB's official instructions didn't mention that the repository URL was for 2.6. I had to follow your updated step 2 with the correct URL in order to use sudo apt-get install mongodb-org. After that it fixed the problem.

Comment: @DanPantry: why not [submit a PR to fix it](https://github.com/mongodb/docs/pull/2365)?

Comment: @DanDascalescu because at the time I had never used MongoDB and didn't want to start correcting the documentation of an application I had never used.

Comment: [Install MongoDb on Ubuntu](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

Comment: It didn't work for me using the last repo for getting the latest version of MongoDB!

Comment: @Lexynux If you are using different version other than ubuntu 12.04 then you need to change the step 2. The answer was default for that version but i have been updated the answer. I hope you will found it helpful now :)

Comment: I tried the command for Ubuntu 14.04 and it still not working!

Comment: I have 16.04 LTS and nothing of here had worked for me, until I bumped this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: This doens't work for me on Ubuntu 14.04. It kept installing mongo 2.4.9.

Comment: This is the log of apt-get update `W: Failed to fetch https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/trusty/mongodb-org/3.6/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  Received HTTP code 405 from proxy after CONNECT`  I guess the mongodb blocked my vm?

Comment: I had this issue and it was because I downloaded a 32-bit version of ubuntu instead of 64. MongoDB will only run on 64-bit. to check this run `getconf LONG_BIT`

Comment: `Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Answer (score 65):

The true problem here may be if you have a **32-bit** system. MongoDB 3.X was never made to be used on a 32-bit system, so the repostories for 32-bit is empty (hence why it is not found). Installing the default 2.X Ubuntu package might be your best bet with:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb
```

Another workaround, if you nevertheless want to get the latest version of Mongo:

You can go to
https://www.mongodb.org/downloads
and use the drop-down to select "Linux 32-bit legacy"

But it comes with severe [limitations](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/137788967/32-bit-limitations)...

> This 32-bit legacy distribution does not include SSL encryption and is
>   limited to around 2GB of data. In general you should use the 64 bit
>   builds. See [here](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/137788967/32-bit-limitations) for more information.

Answer (score 56):

Try without '-org':

> sudo apt-get install -y mongodb

Worked for me!

Comment: This is probably Ubuntu's default package. Not useful if you want the latest mongo.

Comment: This may indeed be the Ubuntu default package. Good for a quick start, but if you specifically need the latest package from mongo.org, then extra steps are required.

Comment: The true problem here may be if you have a 32-bit system. MongoDB 3.X was never made to be used on a 32-bit system, so the repostories for 32-bit is empty (hence why it is not found).

Comment: That is exactly the problem, and this is the real answer :-)
Its just something that Mongo's website doesn't clearly say. At one place they say that you should run MongoDB on 64 bit for production, in another it says that they provide packages for both 32 bit and 64 bit for test environments.

Comment: I've added a more detailed answer below that summarizes the problem (based on all the helpful comments, thank you!) and proposes some workarounds. Could you please upvote that answer instead of this one?

Comment: `Package 'mongodb' has no installation candidate`

Answer (score 7):

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04; and apt still couldn't find package; I tried all the answers above and more.
The URL that worked for me is this:

```
echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
```

Source: http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-14-04/

Answer (score 6):

All steps are correct just change the Step 4 as below

- Step 4: Install the last stable MongoDB version and all the necessary packages on our system

Command: `sudo apt-get install mongodb`

It has worked for me.

Comment: This is installs Ubuntu's default unofficial mongo package which is already mentioned in the top answer by Naim. You don't need to follow the previous steps for this.

Answer (score 5):

If you are currently using the **MongoDB 3.3 Repository** *(as officially currently suggested by MongoDB website)* you should take in consideration that the package name used for version 3.3 is:

> mongodb-org-unstable

Then the proper installation command for this version will be:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org-unstable
```

Considering this, **I will rather suggest to use the current latest stable version (v3.2)** until the v3.3 becomes stable, the commands to install it are listed below:

Download the v3.2 Repository key:

```
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-3.2.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

If you work with **Ubuntu 12.04** or **Mint 13** add the following repository:

```
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu precise/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list
```

If you work with **Ubuntu 14.04** or **Mint 17** add the following repository:

```
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list
```

If you work with **Ubuntu 16.04** or **Mint 18** add the following repository:

```
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list
```

Update the package list and install mongo:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org-unstable`

Answer (score 3):

The currently accepted answer works, but will install an outdated version of Mongo.

The Mongo documentation states that: MongoDB only provides packages for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Precise Pangolin) and 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr). However, These packages may work with other Ubuntu releases.

So, to get the lastest stable Mongo (`3.0`), use this (the different step is the second one):

```
    apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
    echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
    apt-get update
    apt-get install mongodb-org
```

Hope this helps.

---

I would like to add that as a previous step, you must check your GNU/Linux Distro Release, which will construct the Repo list url. For me, as I am using this:

```
DISTRIB_CODENAME=rafaela
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.2 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS"
```

The original 2nd step:

```
"Create a list file for MongoDB": "echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list"
```

**Didn't work** as intended because it generated an incorrect Repo url. Basically, it put the distribution codename **"rafaela"** within the url repo which doesn't exist. You can check the Repo url at your package manager under Software Sources, Additional Repositories.

What I did was to browse the site:

http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/

And I found out that for Ubuntu, "trusty" and "precise" are the only web folders available, not "rafaela".

**Solution**: Open as root the file 'mongodb-org-3.1.list' or 'mongodb.list' and replace "rafaela" or your release version for the corresponding version (for me it was: "trusty"), save the changes and continue with next steps. Also, your package manager can let you change easily the repo url as well.

Hope it works for you.! ---

Answer (score 1):

You first need to add the package database and add the PGP key.

Run the following.

```
#add pgp key
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10

#add package file
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list

#update package list
sudo apt-get update

#install mongo
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

Comment: I already have, it worked perfectly till the third step but then I got the above error.

Comment: That would happen if apt-get update wasn't ran and/or the sources list is empty.  Can you run `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list`?

Comment: Did it, this is what I got `deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu precise/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in 14.04, but I fixed it by these steps:

1. sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
2. echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb- org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
3. sudo apt-get update
4. sudo apt-get install -y mongodb

It worked like charm :)

Comment: This will install the default Ubuntu 2.X package, not the latest 3.X from mongo.org (see comments on other answers above and below)

Comment: i would like you to have a look at the official website

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

in official website there is a mistake in this line
4. sudo apt-get install -y mongodb

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb
```

it works for 32-bit ubuntu, try it.best of luck.

Comment: this is the ubuntu version of mongo, conflicts with mongodb-org

Answer (score 1):

This worked on Ubuntu 17.04

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 2930ADAE8CAF5059EE73BB4B58712A2291FA4AD5

echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.6 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.6.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

If you see a failure like:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-tools_3.6.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/bsondump', which is also in package mongo-tools 3.2.11-1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
```

Then run this command:

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.6 multiverse" |
```

sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.6.list

and

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mongodb-org
```

References:

- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problems on Ubuntu 16.04 when I followed the steps posted on the [official document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/).
Then I **remove the text "[ arch=amd64,arm64 ]" in step2** and it works for me.

```
echo "deb https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list   
apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [official guide](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/installation-ubuntu-community-troubleshooting/), this error occurs if the file
**"/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-6.0.list"** is either misconfigured or missing. Check whether the above file is present or not. If present and misconfigured, then you can fix it by performing the steps provided in the [official guide](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/installation-ubuntu-community-troubleshooting/). And if it is not present, then you need to create the file in the given location. For example in my case, I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, and **"sources.list.d"** folder was not present. So I created that folder using the command **"mkdir sources.list.d"** in the directory **"/etc/apt/"**. And then I retried the installation steps from **"step 2"** onwards as provided in the [official guide for installation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/). This one fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Fixing MongoDB Repository Issue
You'll need to remove the outdated MongoDB Upstart repository and ensure you're using the correct, updated repository for your version of Ubuntu. Here's how you can do that and install MongoDB:

Remove the Outdated Repository
First, find and remove the outdated MongoDB Upstart repository entry. Check your /etc/apt/sources.list and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ directory for any files containing the outdated repository URLs and remove or edit them.

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org*.list
```

This command assumes the MongoDB repository details are in a file within /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ starting with mongodb-org. Adjust the command if the file has a different name.

Add the Correct MongoDB Repository
Follow the updated steps to add the correct MongoDB repository for Ubuntu 22.04:

Import the MongoDB GPG Key:

```
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-7.0.asc | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-7.0.gpg
```

Add the MongoDB Repository:

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-7.0.gpg ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/7.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-7.0.list
```

Update Your Package Lists:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install MongoDB:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc |  gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/mongodb.gpg > /dev/null
```

echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mongodb.gpg ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/6.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-6.0.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mongodb-org

https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/installing-mongodb-over-ubuntu-22-04/159931/90