# MongoDB installation in Ubuntu 14.04 Failed

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-14.04

I followed the steps as mentioned in the official site of MongoDB.

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

Running the last command I get an error:

> E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org

Please help.

Comment: Try: `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb`

Comment: I tried with that command before. It installed with no problem. I thought I should follow the steps as mentioned in the official website. Can I assume the method mentioned in the official website is does not work for Ubuntu 14.04? or Maybe I am making some mistake?

Comment: Well apt-get is not locating the package mongodb-org. Can you provide the link you are using for instructions?>

Comment: I am using this link.http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Hmmm not sure why it does not locate the package that is advocated on the website. Nonetheless, my suggestion should work either. To be on the safe side, try: `sudo apt-get install -y mongo*`, with a wildcard present, it will grab everything mongo related.

Comment: Yes. I have tried the command before. It does work I do know that.

Comment: Either way, your still getting the mongodb package

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't this install the default Ubuntu package rather than the latest release from mongo.org ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28945921/e-unable-to-locate-package-mongodb-org)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Just try

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb
```

Comment: Lovely, this should be updated on official doc steps.

Comment: This will install the default Ubuntu package instead of the latest Mongo.org one. See the other answers on here for alternatives.

Comment: I just ran into this issue as I am writing this. Using this command helped.... When You say it will install old packages do you mean it is not a good idea to use this command?

Comment: This installed MongoDB 2.6 when latest version is 3.4.

Answer (score 11):

[For proper installation of MongoDB, follow these steps](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#import-the-public-key-used-by-the-package-management-system):

### [Note: According to ubuntu 12.06 ,14.04 , 16.04 there is different kind of installation](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#import-the-public-key-used-by-the-package-management-system)

> Below Code is For Ubuntu 14.04 ,And for other version click above link

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
sudo service mongod start
```

//restart your pc if it dosen't starts

**Just in case** commands don't work due to **version change** please refer to [**original source**](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#import-the-public-key-used-by-the-package-management-system)

Comment: i had only posted link and not code ....so got down voted...as links might change ...then wrote proper answer that contains (link+code)

Comment: This is the correct answer for getting a recent version installed.