# MongoDB package installation error

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I am following the instructions to install MongoDB from the following link. I am trying to install MongoDB 3.0, on Ubuntu 13.0

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

When I execute the command 'sudo apt-get update' I get the following error. I googled for this error, but couldn't find anything helpful. Could anyone help me understand why these packages are not available. Due to this error, I am unable to follow the remaining steps.

W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/saucy/mongodb-org/3.0/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/saucy/mongodb-org/3.0/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

Comment: possible duplicate of [E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28945921/e-unable-to-locate-package-mongodb-org)

Answer (score 0):

I have understood the issue and found a fix. I followed this link on stackoverflow.

[E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28945921/e-unable-to-locate-package-mongodb-org)

The issue was caused due to the wrong package URI mentioned in the source.list. So, I executed the following command, which solved my issue.

echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in 14.04, but I fixed it by these steps:

1. sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
2. echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb- org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
3. sudo apt-get update
4. sudo apt-get install -y mongodb

I think i will work on Ubuntu 13.0 also, just have a try :)