# Installing MongoDb on Lubuntu

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I am trying to install MongoDD on [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) following the [official instructions for Ubuntu](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/shell/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/).

But when I try to run this line:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

I get this error:

```
jon@jon-HP-ENVY-17-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org
jon@jon-HP-ENVY-17-Notebook-PC:~$
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28945921/e-unable-to-locate-package-mongodb-org

Answer (score 0):

Try "sudo apt-get update" before "sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org"...

Or try tutorial for Lubuntu, not Ubuntu, like this: http://tutorialforlinux.com/2014/03/12/how-to-install-latest-mongodb-on-lubuntu-12-04-precise-lts-32-64bit-linux-easy-guide/

Answer (score 0):

May be it's beacause of the old MongoDb's version. Try with the latest MondoDb repository url to generate the file.

Before trying `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org` , execute the following commands in your terminal

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10

# following is the repository url for Latest MongoDb version 3.0

echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```