# MongoDB GPG - Invalid Signatures

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I'm installing MongoDB on an Ubuntu 14.04 machine, using the instructions at:
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

So I run:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927
```

And then:

```
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list
```

Followed by:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I then get the following warning at the end of the update:

> W: GPG error: http://repo.mongodb.org trusty/mongodb-org/3.2 Release:
>   The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG D68FA50FEA312927 MongoDB
>   3.2 Release Signing Key

If I ignore the warning and try to run:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

I get:

> WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
>   mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-mongos
>   mongodb-org-tools   mongodb-org E: There are problems and -y was used
>   without --force-yes

Any ideas on how to resolve? Thanks!

Comment: Same error, also 14.04 LTS

Comment: The trouble is still here in Feb'18, and there is working solution below, but not accepted one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46737148/2273305
@assaf-hershko, please consider changing your selection of best answer

Comment: Importing keys as per official installation documentation at https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/ worked for me. As of 2019-06-10 the command to run is `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 2930ADAE8CAF5059EE73BB4B58712A2291FA4AD5`

Comment: Same error also on 20.04 LTS

Answer (score 299, accepted):

Update all expired keys from Ubuntu key server in one command:

```
sudo apt-key list | \
 grep "expired: " | \
 sed -ne 's|pub .*/\([^ ]*\) .*|\1|gp' | \
 xargs -n1 sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys
```

Command explanation:

1. `sudo apt-key list` - lists all keys installed in the system;
2. `grep "expired: "` - leave only lines with expired keys;
3. `sed -ne 's|pub .*/\([^ ]*\) .*|\1|gp'` - extracts keys;
4. `xargs -n1 sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys` - updates keys from Ubuntu key server by found expired ones.

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/837004/33718)

Comment: This worked great on Mint. Note: The argument for the `--recv-key` is the expired key.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore, as the format of `apt-key list` is no longer compatible with the commands in this answer that process it. Instead, run `sudo apt-key list | grep -A 1 expired`. Copy the 40-hex-digit fingerprint. Next, run the command `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys $FINGERPRINT` where `$FINGERPRINT` is the value you copied (if it contains spaces, put quotes around it).

Comment: Just a note: Laurence's solution worked for me, but note that it was an 8-character fingerprint in my case rather than a 40-character one.

Answer (score 58):

Sounds like you need to redo the installation steps for MongoDB.
First, remove any existing repository file for MongoDB. Do as below:

```
$ sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb*.list
```

Next, add the key (without the key, the repository will not load):

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927
```

Now, create a new MongoDB repository list file:

```
$ echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list
```

After adding the repository details, we need to update the packages list:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Now install MongoDB:

```
sudo apt install mongodb-org
```

Comment: The only step which is needed is the key re-import: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927

Comment: Worked for me as well. I think as Ben stated, the re-import is the key to the key.

Comment: Getting E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org

Comment: I followed this advice, and I got another error (public key is not available).

Comment: @Quin can you please remove everything and reinstall again

Answer (score 27):

You don't need to reinstall the mongo packages, but just change the key as following:

List the keys to confirm it is expired:

```
apt-key list | grep "expired:"
```

Replace the key:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 0xd68fa50fea312927
```

The number 0xd68fa50fea312927 is the current valid key id (expires at 2019-10-09), as you can check [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-31459).

Comment: I think this is the method explained in more detail here: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/fix-ubuntu-debian-apt-get-keyexpired-the-following-signatures-were-invalid. This worked for me.

Comment: Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)

Comment: how to find the key?

Answer (score 9):

It seems version 3.2.1 has been released on 11/Jan/2016, and the packages signature is bad since this moment. The packages signature were fine the day before.

refs: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER/fixforversion/15908/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:version-summary-panel

You can either add the --force-yes option, or wait for a few hours that the mongodb team sees and fixes the issue.

There is already a ticket there: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22144

Comment: I used the --force-yes, is there a risk I'm taking with this solution?

Comment: March 2016, it hasn't been fixed yet.

Comment: @retrography yep, they did new release (3.2.4) at 13:38 GMT on March 8, seems their signing script is having problems again

Comment: Still having problem, May 20, 2016 :P

Comment: `WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated! mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-tools mongodb-org` June 13, 2016

Comment: Another solution is to manually download the deb package from the official repo and install them with dpkg -i. This way you can upgrade them when the repo key is fixed.

Comment: August 2016, still not fixed. For more information see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22143

Comment: Still having this problem in November 2016, yet both tickets are closed...

Comment: Still in October 2017

Comment: January 2018, still have it.

Comment: and still in March 2018

Comment: @Lam Yes, there is a risk. The packages are unsigned and therefore insecure. The probability of them being malicious is small but very real.

Comment: almost June 2018 and I guess the problem still persists

Comment: Long story short this is the link that you eventually find has the current key and procedure https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Comment: I am still facing this issue in August, 2020

Answer (score 9):

I also faced this issue when installing MongoDB 4.0 on Ubuntu 16.04.
So I did.

1. `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb*.list` - remove any existing file for MongoDB
2. `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv E52529D4` - add the key
3. `sudo bash -c 'echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.0 multiverse" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list'` - create a new MongoDB repository list file

Now, Complete the installation with an update of repositories then install MongoDB, enable the `mongod` service and start it up, and last, check your MongoDB version:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mongodb-org

systemctl enable mongod.service
systemctl start mongod.service

mongo --version
```

Comment: Appearently the problem gets solved with just step#2, importing the public key in ubuntu key-store. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @FullstackDeveloper how do you find the key `E52529D4`  ?

Answer (score 7):

I also faced this issue when installing MongoDB 3.2 on my ubuntu 16.04 using the below commands. The below solution is provided as the question related to the v3.2 installation of MongoDB

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list
sudo apt-get update
```

After running the above update command i found the following warnings

```
W: GPG error: http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1507497109
W: The repository 'http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 Release' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

On further investigating using the below command to list all the keys

```
sudo apt-key list
```

It shows that the current key is expired on 2017-10-08

```
pub   4096R/EA312927 2015-10-09 [expired: 2017-10-08]
uid                  MongoDB 3.2 Release Signing Key <packaging@mongodb.com>
```

This also made sense as the MongoDB Current Stable Release is now (3.4.9).

To fix the issue first we make a small cleanup  (optional)

1. we remove the old key added

   sudo apt-key list            // List all keys

   sudo apt-key del EA312927   // Find the uid of the key to be deleted

   apt-key list | grep Mongodb // Verify if its deleted
2. Now we remove the MongoDB repo added in /etc/apt/sources.list.d

   sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb*.list
3. Now we install the latest stable version of MongoDB(3.4.9) using below commands

Import the Public Key used by the Ubuntu Package Manager

```
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 0C49F3730359A14518585931BC711F9BA15703C6
```

Create a file list for mongoDB to fetch the current repository

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-3.4.list
```

Install MongoDB

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mongodb-org
```

Answer (score 7):

I experienced the similar problem and got the following error while installing MongoDB 4.2 on Ubuntu 18.04 instance on Google Cloud.

```
W: GPG error: http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.2 Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4B7C549A058F8B6B
E: The repository 'http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.2 Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details
```

The solution that worked from me was running the following command to get the key. I found this on MongoDB official Jira Issue Pages.

```
/usr/bin/curl -sLO https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.2.asc && sudo /usr/bin/apt-key add server-4.2.asc
```

I found this solution in MongoDB official Jira issues. Here is the [link](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-13026) to the issue.

Comment: also works for MongoDB 4.2 and Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Answer (score 5):

The following is important to solve the problem:

```bash
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb*.list
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, and solved it by installing mongodb with tarball method. Refer to the below link for detail.

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux/

Adding details below

1. curl -O https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-i686-3.2.0.tgz
2. tar -zxvf mongodb-linux-i686-3.2.0.tgz
3. mkdir -p mongodb && cp -R -n mongodb-linux-i686-3.2.0/ mongodb
4. export PATH=/bin:$PATH
5. then run mongod (db path might needs to be set)

Answer (score 4):

```
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-3.2.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, so I did:

`root@skarabi:~# apt remove mongodb-org`

Then:

`root@skarabi:~#  sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb*.list`

After :

`root@skarabi:~#  apt update`

Comment: That will just remove the MongoDB repositories from your machine will it not? How are you going to install then?

Comment: and then install it, you can check on this link: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/   There is even the GPG key. It works with me

Comment: This is dangerous and bad. There is no reason to `apt remove` (uninstall) Mongo from your machine simply to get the newest key. You'll be destroying your whole database just to try to pull in an updated key for the apt sources.

Answer (score 1):

Using [dlopatin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46737148/406399) I came up with this for Ubuntu 18.04 since that code doesnt work anymore:

```
sudo apt-key list | \
grep -A 1 "\[expired:" | \
sed -ne 's|^\s\{1,10\}\(\w*\)|\1|gp' | \
xargs -d '\n' sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys
```

1. List keys `sudo apt-key list`
2. Get the expired one and print the next line with the fingerprint `grep -A 1 "\[expired:"`
3. Use sed to extract only the lines starting with space `^\s\{1,10\}`,and select the alphanumeric characters `\(\w*\)`, replace those lines with the selected group which is the fingerprint `\1`, repeat for all returned lines `g`,then print the fingerprint `p`.  That gives: `sed -ne 's|^\s\{1,10\}\(\w*\)|\1|gp'`
4. Use xargs with delimiter for '\n' otherwise it will break on spaces: `xargs -d '\n'`, then pass the fingerprints as arguments to apt-key to update them: `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys` which gives you: `xargs -d '\n' sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys`

Hopefully that is clear.  Ignore the warning about apt-key output parsing :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on ubuntu focal 20.04.01 LTS for installing MongoDB version 3.4.17:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 0C49F3730359A14518585931BC711F9BA15703C6
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list
sudo apt update

apt-cache policy libssl1.0-dev
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0-dev

sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=3.4.17 mongodb-org-server=3.4.17 mongodb-org-shell=3.4.17 mongodb-org-mongos=3.4.17 mongodb-org-tools=3.4.17
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# remove any existing file for MongoDB
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb*.list
# add the key
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv E52529D4
# create a new MongoDB repository list file
sudo bash -c 'echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.0 multiverse" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list'
```

Now, Complete the installation with an update of repositories then install MongoDB, enable the mongod service and start it up, and last, check your MongoDB version:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mongodb-org

mongo --version
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the commands to upgrade the Mongo from 3.6 to 4.0.

Note: I tried this in the Ubuntu 16.04

Stop the Mongo service

`$ sudo systemctl stop mongod.service`

`$ sudo mv /etc/mongod.conf /etc/mongodnew.conf`

Import the public key as mentioned in the MongoDB official documentation https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

`wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -`

Create a list file for MongoDB.

`echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list`

Reload local package database

`sudo apt-get update`

Upgrade the MongoDB packages [ Specific Versoion]

`sudo apt-get upgrade -y --allow-unauthenticated mongodb-org=4.0.27 mongodb-org-server=4.0.27 mongodb-org-shell=4.0.27 mongodb-org-mongos=4.0.27 mongodb-org-tools=4.0.27`

Done !!!

Do the validation by running the following command

`mongod --version`

Rename the mongodnew.conf file

`sudo mv /etc/mongodnew.conf /etc/mongod.conf`

`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

`sudo systemctl start mongod`

`sudo systemctl status mongod`

Login to the Mongo Shell and set FCV

````
db.adminCommand( { getParameter: 1, featureCompatibilityVersion: 1 } )

db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "4.0" } )


For ubuntu 20.04 Please follow this.

https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongo-db-4-0-gpg-key-expired-for-ubuntu-18-04/230854/2

```echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 trusted=yes ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 multiverse" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list```
````

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar GPG error while trying to run `sudo apt-get update`. Here's how I resolved it:

- `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-7.0.list` (enter the correct .list path)
- Change
  `deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-7.0.gpg ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mong>` to `deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-7.0.gpg ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mong>` added **arch=amd64,arm64** just inside the bracket after deb
- Save and exit

You may encounter similar error for other .list files present in the folder. If you follow the same steps for them as well, the command should execute as expected.