# how to install mongodb on ubuntu 16.04.1?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I have used the instructions from the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

after this command:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

I get this warning:

```
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-tools mongodb-org
E: There were unauthenticated packages and -y was used without --allow-unauthenticated
```

Its instruction to start and test gives the following:

```
sudo service mongod start

cat /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
cat: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log: No such file or directory
```

Comment: May be you missed some steps. Did you begin executing commands from here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#import-the-public-key-used-by-the-package-management-system

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure I've complete all the steps in the correct order. I've tried it serveral times.

Comment: May be this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733340/mongodb-gpg-invalid-signatures

Comment: I've actually had a look at that already. The signatures aren't invalid though.

Comment: Can you please try this : `sudo apt-get --allow-unauthenticated install -y mongodb-org`

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, you could solve the problem by `bypassing the gpg signature checks of apt` using :

```
sudo apt-get --allow-unauthenticated install -y mongodb-org
```

You might want to have a look at more `configuration options` in detail along with right practices of using this appraoch here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/74345/how-do-i-bypass-ignore-the-gpg-signature-checks-of-apt

Answer (score 0):

The mongodb docs have a great page on installing the latest mongo on Ubuntu. You can find it at: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

I'd recommend uninstalling mongodb and following the instructions on the previously mentioned page.