# nodejs Mongodb error whie running app.js file

Tags: node.js

```
enter code here
```

> MongoError: failed to connect to server [96:27017] on first connect
>   [MongoError: connect ETIMEDOUT 218.93.250.18:27017]
>       at Pool. (C:\Users\shubham\Desktop\chato\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:336:35)
>       at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>       at Pool.emit (events.js:211:7)
>       at Connection. (C:\Users\shubham\Desktop\chato\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:280:12)
>       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:317:30)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
>       at Connection.emit (events.js:214:7)
>       at Socket. (C:\Users\shubham\Desktop\chato\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:187:49)
>       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
>       at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
>       at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

Comment: You need to have mongodb server running for this...

Comment: no do we need mongoDb server to run?coz m storing data on mongolab

Comment: Then check the configuration for mongolab. Clearly 96:27017 is not a correct Mongo lab url

Comment: mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds145293.mlab.com:45293/chaton

Comment: this is correct url there in no issue with url also

Comment: Run `mongod` in the terminal and run the node server that should solve the issue

As your in Mongolab make sure you able to reach the Mongolab url from any Mongo DB client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//step1)
sudo npm install mongodb@latest

//step2)
echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen

//step3)
sudo apt-get update

//step4)
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse

//step5)
sudo apt-get install MongoDB

//step6)
nodemon serve
```

hopefully, it solved the same error I am facing while working on Angular8 with Nodejs and using MongoDB as a database.

for fetching above steps I followed these links:

- [Install mongodb on debian (guide)](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/)
- [E: unable to locate package mongodb-org (question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28945921/e-unable-to-locate-package-mongodb-org.)
- [MongoDB GPG - Invalid Signatures (question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733340/mongodb-gpg-invalid-signatures)

Answer (score 0):

Exactly!! this is the correct url
    mongodb://:@ds145293.mlab.com:45293/chat‌​on

But.. Did you replace `<dbuser>` and `<dbpassword>` with the db user login. 
Note: I am not talking about the Mongolab login. Inside the Mongo lab there should be an option to add users for the DB named `chaton` and those credentials like dbuser and dbpassword should be replaced. 
For example:
User:admin
password:password
Now the url will be like : 
`mongodb://admin:password@ds145293.mlab.com:45293/chat‌​on`

Hope you got clarified :)

Comment: Yeah i have done exactly this before still it is giving me error

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?