# Upgraded MongoDB to 2.6 and now get "ClientCursorMonitor exception"

Tags: mongodb

I did not manually upgrade the database. I updated the packages on my Ubuntu virtual machine and it updated the mongodb to 2.6.10 from 2.4.10. Now the mongodb process won't start. I read that there are some changes to the way authentication is done in 2.6. I am not sure if that is what is causing this error?

```
2018-02-10T06:52:42.780-0600 ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2018-02-10T06:52:42.782-0600 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=3705 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit
2018-02-10T06:52:42.782-0600 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.10
2018-02-10T06:52:42.782-0600 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
2018-02-10T06:52:42.782-0600 [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2018-02-10T06:52:42.782-0600 [initandlisten] build info: Linux lgw01-12 3.19.0-25-generic #26~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:16:20 UTC 2015 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_58
2018-02-10T06:52:42.782-0600 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2018-02-10T06:52:42.782-0600 [initandlisten] options: { config: "mongodb.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017 }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb", journal: { enabled: true },
smallFiles: true }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2018-02-10T06:52:42.785-0600 [initandlisten] journal dir=/var/lib/mongodb/journal
2018-02-10T06:52:42.785-0600 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2018-02-10T06:52:42.782-0600 [initandlisten] options: { config: "mongodb.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017 }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb", journal: { enabled: true },
smallFiles: true }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2018-02-10T06:52:42.785-0600 [initandlisten] journal dir=/var/lib/mongodb/journal
2018-02-10T06:52:42.785-0600 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2018-02-10T06:52:42.914-0600 [initandlisten] admin.system.version Assertion failure 0 == _descriptor->version() || 1 == _descriptor->version() src/mongo/db/index/btree_based_access_method.cp
p 54
2018-02-10T06:52:42.918-0600 [initandlisten] admin.system.version 0xedb3e9 0xe6fb3f 0xe4aae2 0x963f2c 0x96226c 0x740760 0x742c0b 0x743ec8 0x723177 0x72f913 0xaeb109 0x86eda6 0x86effa 0x6d9f9
8 0x6ddef7 0x6c18aa 0x6be82e 0x61fc9a 0x620903 0x5e943c
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x39) [0xedb3e9]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10logContextEPKc+0x21f) [0xe6fb3f]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo12verifyFailedEPKcS1_j+0x142) [0xe4aae2]
 mongod() [0x963f2c]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo17BtreeAccessMethodC1EPNS_17IndexCatalogEntryE+0x2c) [0x96226c]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo12IndexCatalog19_createAccessMethodEPKNS_15IndexDescriptorEPNS_17IndexCatalogEntryE+0x200) [0x740760]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo12IndexCatalog24_setupInMemoryStructuresEPNS_15IndexDescriptorE+0xeb) [0x742c0b]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo12IndexCatalog4initEv+0x258) [0x743ec8]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10CollectionC2ERKNS_10StringDataEPNS_16NamespaceDetailsEPNS_8DatabaseE+0x297) [0x723177]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo8Database13getCollectionERKNS_10StringDataE+0xe3) [0x72f913]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo9getRunnerEPNS_14CanonicalQueryEPPNS_6RunnerEm+0x89) [0xaeb109]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo7Helpers7findOneERKNS_10StringDataERKNS_7BSONObjEb+0xb6) [0x86eda6]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo7Helpers7findOneERKNS_10StringDataERKNS_7BSONObjERS4_b+0x2a) [0x86effa]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo31AuthzManagerExternalStateMongod7findOneERKNS_15NamespaceStringERKNS_7BSONObjEPS4_+0x88) [0x6d9f98]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo30AuthzManagerExternalStateLocal29getStoredAuthorizationVersionEPi+0x67) [0x6ddef7]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo20AuthorizationManager23getAuthorizationVersionEPi+0x34a) [0x6c18aa]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo9authindex22configureSystemIndexesERKNS_10StringDataE+0x3e) [0x6be82e]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo14_initAndListenEi+0xada) [0x61fc9a]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo13initAndListenEi+0x23) [0x620903]
 mongod(main+0x23c) [0x5e943c]
2018-02-10T06:52:42.919-0600 [clientcursormon] admin.system.version Assertion failure 0 == _descriptor->version() || 1 == _descriptor->version() src/mongo/db/index/btree_based_access_method.
cpp 54
2018-02-10T06:52:42.922-0600 [clientcursormon] admin.system.version 0xedb3e9 0xe6fb3f 0xe4aae2 0x963f2c 0x96226c 0x740760 0x742c0b 0x743ec8 0x723177 0x72f913 0x72ad7a 0x75e005 0xe4dcad 0x7f5
6a1b765d5 0x7f56a10c96ba 0x7f569feb141d
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x39) [0xedb3e9]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10logContextEPKc+0x21f) [0xe6fb3f]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo12verifyFailedEPKcS1_j+0x142) [0xe4aae2]
 mongod() [0x963f2c]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo17BtreeAccessMethodC1EPNS_17IndexCatalogEntryE+0x2c) [0x96226c]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo12IndexCatalog19_createAccessMethodEPKNS_15IndexDescriptorEPNS_17IndexCatalogEntryE+0x200) [0x740760]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo12IndexCatalog24_setupInMemoryStructuresEPNS_15IndexDescriptorE+0xeb) [0x742c0b]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo12IndexCatalog4initEv+0x258) [0x743ec8]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10CollectionC2ERKNS_10StringDataEPNS_16NamespaceDetailsEPNS_8DatabaseE+0x297) [0x723177]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo8Database13getCollectionERKNS_10StringDataE+0xe3) [0x72f913]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo19GlobalCursorIdCache14timeoutCursorsEj+0x7ba) [0x72ad7a]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo19ClientCursorMonitor3runEv+0x95) [0x75e005]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo13BackgroundJob7jobBodyEv+0x14d) [0xe4dcad]
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so.1.58.0(+0x115d5) [0x7f56a1b765d5]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x76ba) [0x7f56a10c96ba]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7f569feb141d]
2018-02-10T06:52:42.922-0600 [clientcursormon] ERROR: backgroundjob ClientCursorMonitor exception: assertion src/mongo/db/index/btree_based_access_method.cpp:54
2018-02-10T06:52:42.922-0600 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 0 assertion src/mongo/db/index/btree_based_access_method.cpp:54, terminating
2018-02-10T06:52:42.922-0600 [initandlisten] dbexit:
2018-02-10T06:52:42.922-0600 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2018-02-10T06:52:42.922-0600 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2018-02-10T06:52:42.922-0600 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2018-02-10T06:52:42.922-0600 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2018-02-10T06:52:42.922-0600 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
2018-02-10T06:52:42.922-0600 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2018-02-10T06:52:42.922-0600 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2018-02-10T06:52:42.922-0600 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2018-02-10T06:52:42.922-0600 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
2018-02-10T06:52:42.922-0600 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
2018-02-10T06:52:42.924-0600 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock
```

Below is the truncated apt log:

```
Log started: 2018-02-01  18:11:44
Unpacking linux-image-4.4.0-1050-aws (4.4.0-1050.59) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-aws_4.4.0.1050.52_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-aws (4.4.0.1050.52) over (4.4.0.1049.51) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-aws_4.4.0.1050.52_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-aws (4.4.0.1050.52) over (4.4.0.1049.51) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1050.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1050_4.4.0-1050.59_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1050 (4.4.0-1050.59) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-4.4.0-1050-aws.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-4.4.0-1050-aws_4.4.0-1050.59_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.4.0-1050-aws (4.4.0-1050.59) ...
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-aws_4.4.0.1050.52_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-aws (4.4.0.1050.52) over (4.4.0.1049.51) ...
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-shell_3.4.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-shell (3.4.10) over (3.4.9) ...
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-server_3.4.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-server (3.4.10) over (3.4.9) ...
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-mongos_3.4.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-mongos (3.4.10) over (3.4.9) ...
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-tools_3.4.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-tools (3.4.10) over (3.4.9) ...
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org_3.4.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org (3.4.10) over (3.4.9) ...
Setting up linux-image-aws (4.4.0.1050.52) ...
Setting up linux-aws-headers-4.4.0-1050 (4.4.0-1050.59) ...
Setting up linux-headers-4.4.0-1050-aws (4.4.0-1050.59) ...
Setting up linux-headers-aws (4.4.0.1050.52) ...
Setting up linux-aws (4.4.0.1050.52) ...
Setting up mongodb-org-shell (3.4.10) ...
Setting up mongodb-org-server (3.4.10) ...
Setting up mongodb-org-mongos (3.4.10) ...
Setting up mongodb-org-tools (3.4.10) ...
Setting up mongodb-org (3.4.10) ...
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-1022-aws
Updating /boot/grub/menu.lst ... done

Setting up overlayroot (0.27ubuntu1.5) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/overlayroot.conf ...
Setting up unattended-upgrades (0.90ubuntu0.9) ...
Setting up cloud-init (17.1-46-g7acc9e68-0ubuntu1~16.04.1) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/cloud/templates/hosts.suse.tmpl ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/cloud/templates/ntp.conf.sles.tmpl ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/cloud/templates/sources.list.debian.tmpl ...
Leaving 'diversion of /etc/init/ureadahead.conf to /etc/init/ureadahead.conf.disabled by cloud-init'
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.10) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-1050-aws
W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.
Setting up ubuntu-server (1.361.1) ...
Setting up python3-distupgrade (1:16.04.23) ...
Setting up python3-update-manager (1:16.04.10) ...
Setting up ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (1:16.04.23) ...
Setting up update-manager-core (1:16.04.10) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Processing triggers for resolvconf (1.78ubuntu5) ...
Log ended: 2018-02-01  18:13:05
```

After the apt update... this is the log from mongodb...

```
2018-02-01T18:22:07.805-0600 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] got signal 15 (Terminated), will terminate after current cmd ends
2018-02-01T18:22:07.817-0600 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2018-02-01T18:22:07.820-0600 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 7
2018-02-01T18:22:07.820-0600 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 8
2018-02-01T18:22:07.821-0600 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2018-02-01T18:22:07.821-0600 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2018-02-01T18:22:07.831-0600 I FTDC     [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down full-time diagnostic data capture
2018-02-01T18:22:07.846-0600 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2018-02-01T18:22:07.846-0600 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: final commit...
2018-02-01T18:22:07.846-0600 I JOURNAL  [signalProcessingThread] journalCleanup...
2018-02-01T18:22:07.846-0600 I JOURNAL  [signalProcessingThread] removeJournalFiles
2018-02-01T18:22:07.850-0600 I JOURNAL  [signalProcessingThread] old journal file will be removed: /var/lib/mongodb/journal/j._0
2018-02-01T18:22:07.860-0600 I JOURNAL  [signalProcessingThread] Terminating durability thread ...
2018-02-01T18:22:07.953-0600 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread stopped
2018-02-01T18:22:07.953-0600 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread stopped
2018-02-01T18:22:07.953-0600 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: closing all files...
2018-02-01T18:22:07.953-0600 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] closeAllFiles() finished
2018-02-01T18:22:07.953-0600 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2018-02-01T18:22:07.954-0600 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] now exiting
2018-02-01T18:22:07.954-0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:0
2018-02-01T18:22:41.706-0600 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2018-02-01T18:22:41.719-0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1307 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=ip-
2018-02-01T18:22:41.719-0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.10
2018-02-01T18:22:41.719-0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 078f28920cb24de0dd479b5ea6c66c644f6326e9
2018-02-01T18:22:41.719-0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2018-02-01T18:22:41.719-0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2018-02-01T18:22:41.719-0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2018-02-01T18:22:41.719-0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2018-02-01T18:22:41.719-0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
2018-02-01T18:22:41.719-0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2018-02-01T18:22:41.719-0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2018-02-01T18:22:41.719-0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongodb.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mo
ngodb", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log" } }
2018-02-01T18:22:41.827-0600 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /var/lib/mongodb created by the 'mmapv1' storage engine, so setting the active
 storage engine to 'mmapv1'.
2018-02-01T18:22:41.854-0600 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journal dir=/var/lib/mongodb/journal
2018-02-01T18:22:41.855-0600 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2018-02-01T18:22:41.855-0600 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten]
2018-02-01T18:22:41.855-0600 E JOURNAL  [initandlisten] Insufficient free space for journal files
2018-02-01T18:22:41.855-0600 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] Please make at least 3379MB available in /var/lib/mongodb/journal or use --smallfiles
2018-02-01T18:22:41.855-0600 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten]
2018-02-01T18:22:41.866-0600 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 15926 Insufficient free space for journals, terminating
2018-02-01T18:22:41.866-0600 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2018-02-01T18:22:41.866-0600 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2018-02-01T18:22:41.866-0600 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2018-02-01T18:22:41.866-0600 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2018-02-01T18:22:41.866-0600 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2018-02-01T18:22:41.866-0600 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2018-02-01T18:22:41.866-0600 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2018-02-01T18:22:41.866-0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2018-02-01T18:22:41.866-0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

After seeing the insufficient free space message in the logs, I added smallFiles:true to the config file and restarted the database which is what caused the original error reported above.

Comment: Did you stop the mongod process before you ran apt-get update? Could you also update your OP with the relevant info from the apt-get update command

Comment: Here is my apt log. I think I may have not stopped mongod process before the update... I thought apt would stop the process just like it does for apache and mysql before upgrade. Below is the truncated apt log:

Comment: Add the apt log to your OP :-) That’s why I’ve asked to see them. To check if mongod was stopped, before hand. I suspect not

Comment: Thanks.I appreciate your help so much. I could not add everything, so I added where I could see mongodb notes.

Comment: Is there anything in your mongod log with coincides with when the apt-get update ran to prove mongo was first stopped before the rpm was unpacked?

Comment: I added the mongodb logs to OP. Looks like the shutdown was normal.

Comment: Your mongod logs report after the update mongo being v3.4.10

Comment: The error you reported shows mongo v2.6.10. Which doesn’t tally with what you’ve said in your OP. You’ll get the error you’re getting if you’ve upgraded to v3.4 and then try and start with v2.6 binaries

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the oldest log I can find that was logged on Feb 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going from what’s in you OP. You’ve upgraded to mongo 3.4.10

```
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-shell_3.4.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-shell (3.4.10) over (3.4.9) ...
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-server_3.4.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-server (3.4.10) over (3.4.9) ...
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-mongos_3.4.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-mongos (3.4.10) over (3.4.9) ...
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-tools_3.4.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-tools (3.4.10) over (3.4.9) ...
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org_3.4.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org (3.4.10) over (3.4.9) ...
```

After your `apt-get update`, or I should say during...

```
2018-02-01T18:22:41.719-0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1307 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=ip-
2018-02-01T18:22:41.719-0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.10
```

You hit:

```
2018-02-01T18:22:41.855-0600 E JOURNAL  [initandlisten] Insufficient free space for journal files
2018-02-01T18:22:41.855-0600 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] Please make at least 3379MB
```

This clearly states, your `update` has failed due to disk space. Your logs clearly show you’ve upgraded from `3.4.9` to `3.4.10`

Not sure then about this entry as clearly doesn’t tie in with the other logs.

```
2018-02-10T06:52:42.782-0600 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=3705 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit
2018-02-10T06:52:42.782-0600 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.10
```

You need to check you ENV and sure you’re using the correct mongo binaries (see below for command).

You could try your luck, if it’s just your dev VM and try re-installing the `3.4.10` binaries, after addressing the disk space issue, but like you mentioned you’ve switched to small files.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

Which will install all the components again.

Ensure your PATH is using the correct `mongod` binaries, `mongod —version`

Comment: N3i1's guess was right. The update of mongodb somehow went wrong. I had to get the new key by following instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46737148/9342458 after which I did apt-get install -y mongodb-org and it worked. Thanks N3i1 so much !!!