# Install latest MongoDB on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-16.10

I am trying to install MongoDB on `Ubuntu 16.10`, I have followed the steps in the MongoDB official website.

1. `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 0C49F3730359A14518585931BC711F9BA15703C6`
2. `echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list`
3. `sudo apt-get update`
4. `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org`

---

I followed these steps but I am getting the error:

> E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org

Could this be because my Ubuntu is not 64 bit but i686?

Comment: Please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28945921/e-unable-to-locate-package-mongodb-org

Comment: @Omprakash I did follow on that and it seems to be working now, I just need to make sure it really did

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28945921/e-unable-to-locate-package-mongodb-org)

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution to this problem. Follow these steps:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update -o Acquire::CompressionTypes::Order::=gz
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and then try to use:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

I hope it helps!