# Error installing mongodb 2.6.2 on raspberry pi3

Tags: node.js, mongodb, raspberry-pi3

Hi am new to raspberry pi3 armv7 32bit am trying to install mongodb 2.6.2. i have tried many options to install but all no hope. Here is the recent error i got below

This is the command i use below: 
sudo apt-get install mongodb-org=2.6.2 mongodb-org-server=2.6.2 mongodb-org-shell=2.6.2 mongodb-org-mongos2.6.2 mongodb-org-tools=2.6.2

This is the output on Raspberry pi3 armv7 command line

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org
E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org-server
E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org-shell
E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org-mongos2.6.2
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'mongodb-org-mongos2.6.2'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'mongodb-org-mongos2.6.2'
E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org-tools

Comment: Please format your text accordingly. Also, try a `sudo apt-get update` first.

Comment: I have run the command multiple times

Comment: You edited your 'code', but didn't format it. Can you please do that @Manunyi?

Answer (score 1):

Kindly go through the below link might help to solve the same.

[E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28945921/e-unable-to-locate-package-mongodb-org)

Comment: Thank you much for your concern. I have check the links but after all  i still get this message.  
mongodb is already the newest version (1:2.4.14-4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.