# Mongodump: Error parsing command line: unrecognised option '--uri'

Tags: linux, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to achieve a database dump using this command:

> mongodump --uri
> mongodb+srv://ACC_NAME:PASSWORD@cluster0.fklgt.mongodb.net/DATABASE_NAME

But, I keep getting this error:

> Error parsing command line: unrecognised option '--uri'

---

**CONTEXT:**

I have done this several times before on my local machine. And now I am attempting to do this on a VPS where I am installing mongodb from scratch.

I tried installing it following the [official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) until I reached this step:

> sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org

Which throws this error:

> E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org

After doing some research, I have found this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28945921/e-unable-to-locate-package-mongodb-org) where most answers say that I should just:

> At first try with this command: sudo apt-get install -y mongodb
>
> This is the unofficial mongodb package provided by Ubuntu and it is
> not maintained by MongoDB and conflict with MongoDB’s offically
> supported packages.

So I did exactly that, and the rest is what I explained earlier in this post.

---

> `mongo --version`
> MongoDB shell version: 2.6.10
>
> `mongod --version`
> db version v2.6.10
>
> `hostnamectl`
> Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS
> Kernel: Linux 4.4.0-210-generic
> Architecture: x86-64

Comment: I think you need at least MongoDB version 3.6 in order to use the +srv connection type

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error as well when I was trying to archive the data with mingo.

command executed from mingo

```
 mongodb-database-tools-macos-x86_64-100.7.5/bin/mongodump --uri="mongodb://xxx:@host:8001/db?appName=mingo",--archive="<any_path>",--db="Billing",--gzip,--forceTableScan
```

As I check my CPU architecture, I found I use the incorrect mongodb tool. [The tool site suggest me to download ARM64 version](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools). But I should use X86 version. After change the correct tool package, everything is fine.

```
  Darwin CNL-C02FQ094ML87 22.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 22.5.0: Thu Jun  8 22:22:22 PDT 2023; root:xnu-8796.121.3~7/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

[image]