# I can’t install mongodb: E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I have been trying to install mongodb following the [official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/). So I followed these steps:

**STEP 1:**

```
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-5.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

**STEP 2:**

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/5.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-5.0.list
```

**STEP 3:**

```
sudo apt-get update
```

When I reach this step:

**STEP 4:**

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

This error gets thrown.

> E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org

I looked it up all over the internet and I couldn't find any solution even though it has been asked several times;

After doing some research, I have found this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28945921/e-unable-to-locate-package-mongodb-org) where most answers say that I should just:

> At first try with this command: sudo apt-get install -y mongodb
>
> This is the unofficial mongodb package provided by Ubuntu and it is
> not maintained by MongoDB and conflict with MongoDB’s offically
> supported packages.

But, this seems to be an outdated answer which explains when I tried to do mongodump using the installed mongodb with that approach, it [did not work](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongodump-error-parsing-command-line-unrecognised-option-uri/124217).

---

After using the *Outdated approach*, this the installed mongodb info. I do understand they're outdated.

> `mongo --version`
> MongoDB shell version: 2.6.10
>
> `mongod --version`
> db version v2.6.10

This is the system info.

> `hostnamectl`
> Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS
> Kernel: Linux 4.4.0-210-generic
> Architecture: x86-64

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: The docs page you linked says both that 5.0 supports Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial on x86_64 and that it removes support for Xenial on x86_84.  Perhaps this is in need of a bug report?

Comment: Nope, all I had to is install  MongoDB v4.4 on Ubuntu 16.04 as Ubuntu 16.04 support is dropped in version 5.0+. Here's the link: https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.4/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last release of MongoDB for Xenial was MongoDB 4.4, as seen [in the software's repository for Xenial](https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/xenial/mongodb-org/4.4/). Thus, you won't be able to install MongoDB 5.0 (I assume that's what you are trying to do) from the official repository; however you can install the software using a `.tgz Tarball`, as specified in [Install MongoDB Community on Ubuntu using .tgz Tarball](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-tarball/).